# Selection of data in a region of interest in a matrix (with Mathematica)

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I am having a (mathematica 8.0.1.0-) problem which I cannot solve by myself. 
I have measurement data in a matrix, I want to select some of them and then add them up.

To explain my problem better, here an easy example. The data can be produced by a matrix S:

```
S = Table[ -Sin[i/2] - Sin[j/2], {i,20}, {j,20}];
```

They can be nicely plotted with:

```
xmin = N[Min[S]]; 
xmax = N[Max[S]]; 
mycolorfun = Function[ Blend[{Blue,Cyan,Green,Yellow,Red},#] ];
```

and

```
MatrixPlot[S, PlotRange -> {All,All,All}, AspectRatio -> 1/1,
   ColorFunction -> (mycolorfun[ Rescale[ #1{xmin,xmax} ] ]&),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> Automatic,
   FrameLabel -> {y,x} ]
```

Then one should get a picture similar to this one:

[image]

Now I want to select the data which are inside of the brown drawn polygon. These data should be added up at the end.

How can I do this? 
Ok, I could use rectangles and build a sub-matrix by choosing/guessing good start and end indices. Then I just have to build the sum of this sub-matrix. But I would prefer polygons (more precise if we do not argue about little problems with the matrix values which are crossed by the line of the polygon). And I would love it if I could select my region of interest (ROI) directly by “painting” the polygon into the Matrix (no more time consuming choosing/guessing of matrix indices).
Could somebody here help me with my problem? If it is not solvable with mathematica, is there some other program which I could use?

I would be very happy about some help and hints!

Comment: A point of note, the code blocks require a blank line preceding them, so I fixed it for you.  I also reformatted the code a bit and hid the link behind clickable text for readability.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question! Since I am new here, I had some problems with editing by myself. I try to make it better next time.

Comment: Not a problem. Your new here, and laying out your questions/answers takes practice.

Comment: Thank you @belisarius and @rcollyer for editing my text. It is really nice to see that my picture is directly in my post now. That makes it more understandable!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If selecting the area of interest graphically by hand is not a problem, then you could:

First, create an image out of your data, using a visualization which makes it easy for you to select manually afterward:

```
S = Table[-Sin[i/50.] - Sin[j/50.], {i, 400}, {j, 400}];
img = ReliefImage@S
```

Then use the Front End Graphic Tools to draw the polygon over the region that interests you (right click mouse button):

[image]

Follow by getting the mask that corresponds to your polygon (again, right click button):

[image]

Finally, make a binary image out of the mask and use it to recover the sum of the pixel inside the polygon:

```
Total[S*ImageData@mask, Infinity]
```

The whole process looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: If you'd like to define your area of interest using a free-hand contour, use the Free-hand line tool instead of polygon. Make sure to increase the width of the stroke so that it is easy to close the contour when drawing. You may do so by moving the Stroke>Thickness slider to the right.

That would look like this:

[image]

Then create the mask by filling the inside of the free-hand contour using the function `FillingTransform`, and proceed as before:

[image]

Comment: OMG! That is exactly the solution I have been searching for! Thank you very much! 
I just made some smaller modifications. For example, I am using my own ColorFunction in the ReliefImage (out of a question of taste) and I am creating an additional matrix to plot my region of interest again. I am doing this with: SROI=MatrixForm[S*ImageData@mask]; Then I reduce the tensor SROI to a matrix with
SROImatrix=SROI[[1,All,All]][[All,All,1]]; So I can easily work with the SROImatrix to calculate the sum (Total[SROImatrix,2]) and to plot it.
That is working so fine, I almost cannot believe this!

Comment: Ok, it also would be great if one can paint a freehand line and not only a polygon over the region of interest. But at the moment I am failing in filling the inside of a closed freehand line. Since I can adjust the vertices of my polygon afterwards, I do not really care about this problem. LOL, I am just happy that there is such a extremely nice solution :-) Thank you again for this helpful post!

Comment: @user842603 I have edited my answer to show how to use a free-hand contour. This should answer your question. Besides, may I ask you to add the tag image-processing to your question?

Comment: @user, @Matthias I've added the tag. I'd suggest that the question be slightly reworded to make it clearer that an image-processing answer is required; at the moment, it starts with "I have measurement data in a matrix, I want to select some of them and then add them up."

Comment: @acl Thanks. Image processing is just a means, not an end here. Would restating like this be better? "I have a 2d array of data measurements"

Comment: @Matthias I just suggested what I did because I, at least, did not interpret his question this way. It seems that only I had trouble understanding it though, so maybe it's fine as it is...

Comment: @acl Then, because you perceive a confusion, you are the best person to make a good suggestion! Just trying to help here...

Comment: @Matthias Ah, that is also easier than thought (I did not know the FillingTransform)! Thanks for solving this problem too. With the possibility to paint free-hand contours all my needs are perfectly satisfied now.   @acl Thank you for adding the tag image-processing to my question. I think it fits to my question, although I had not thought at this key word when I wrote my question.

Comment: @Matthias and @acl Sorry for confusing you and perhaps other users with my question! Unfortunately, my English is bad and my knowledge in programming is low, so I was not able to describe my problem better.  
Well, I started with “I am having a mathematica-problem” because I desired a mathematica solution and because I once have seen processes like Matthias’ solution on a computer whose operation system and software are unknown to me. Since I knew that there is a solution for my problem, I tried to find one with mathematica but only with the help of the people here I could find one!

Comment: @Matthias Some of my data would need a region of interest which has the form of a flat torus (like the surface of a CD; a disk from which a part is cut off). I have tried it for some time but I have not figured it out yet. Please, could you enlighten me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @partial81 There are various approaches to try. First, try to draw a circles (not a disk) but with a very high thickness. It that's not enough, you could draw two (or more) masks and then perform simple arithmetic operations to get the union, the intersection, the complement, etc.

Comment: @Matthias Ok, drawing of lines with very high thickness was also my first approach. I just thought that there could be a nicer solution. But as long as this is working for me, I am satisfied. Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this:

```
upl = 20;
s = Table[-Sin[i/2] - Sin[j/2], {i, upl}, {j, upl}];

xmin = N[Min[s]]; xmax = N[Max[s]]; mycolorfun = 
Function[Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Red}, #]];

mp = MatrixPlot[s, PlotRange -> {All, All, All}, AspectRatio -> 1/1, 
ColorFunction -> (mycolorfun[Rescale[#1, {xmin, xmax}]] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> Automatic, 
FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}];
Manipulate[
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = 
 Floor /@ {{p1[[1]], upl - p1[[2]]}, {p2[[1]], upl - p2[[2]]}};
    mp,
{{p1, {1, 1}}, Locator}, {{p2, {19, 19}}, Locator}]

Dynamic[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
Dynamic[N@s[[y2 ;; y1, x1 ;; x2]] // MatrixForm]
```

which produces things like
[image]
with the part of the matrix updated live as you move the locators.

To create polygons instead, just add more locators. Selecting the part of the matrix is then more complicated and it depends on how you want things output.

Comment: Thank you acl (I hope you like Dresden; do you speak German too?) for his detailed answer.  I tried your suggestion, and it even worked for my real, big (2048 x 2048) matrices. Adding more locators is simple (and it is great that you can readout their coordinates/indices so easily), but you are right:  Selecting the part of the matrix in which I am interested in, is then really more complicated. Since I have read your answer, I am thinking and trying to find a solution for more than two locators (and with it for pentagons and hexagons and so on) but I have not had a good idea until now.

Comment: I just can tell you, that I think that a hexagon should be always good enough for me to enclose the regions of interest in my matrix. 
As output I could imagine that I produce a new matrix (stretched by the 4 of the 6 locators (or even more) which have the minimum and maximum indices). The parts of the new matrix which are outside of the region of interest could be filled with 0. So, the sum of the events would be correctly calculated if I use this new matrix.
But I really have no idea how I can implement this.

Comment: @user Yes, if you select a polygonal region it is not so simple to extract the relevant elements, and using them is probably also cumbersome. Perhaps you can ask another, separate and more specific, question on this here. [Dresden is very nice by the way, thanks :)]

Comment: Thanks again for your reply and your efforts. Have you seen Matthias Odisios suggestion? I did not expect that there is such a nice way to solve my problem. But I think I will also use some parts of your suggestion for some other problems. 
Nice to hear that you like Dresden, I should visit this city one day too ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If I got it right, you need to find a connected component of similar pixel values.

You can use image processing functions:

First [Binarize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html) the image using an appropriate threshold.  Then use [MorphologicalComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html) that will identify all connected regions.  Finally, you can extract the image data and use `Pick` to get the pixel values corresponding to the component you are interested in.

**EDIT:** Here's an illustration of the concept:

[image]

Comment: but if he wanted automated selection, wouldn't it be better to do it directly on the original matrix? using eg `Position`?

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs for this totally different approach. Unfortunately, I cannot upload one of the matrix-plots with the real measurement data at the moment. There one could see that I would get into troubles if I try your solution. The reason is simple: there are several areas which have similar pixel values. For my analysis, I have to count the number of events in these areas separately. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier!

Comment: @user, look at the second example for `MorphologicalComponents`, and you'll see that each disconnected region is treated separately. This implies, that you just have to find a threshold for `Binarize` that will create these disconnected regions in your data. Then, use `MorphologicalComponents` to number each region.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply and your efforts. I think I will follow Matthias Odisios suggestion. Somehow he made something like a very fruitful mix out of yours and acls suggestions.

Comment: @user Finally got the time to add an example calculation.

Comment: Daer Szabolcs, thank you very much for adding here this precise suggestion. I admit that it works really fine for the example but less well for my real matrices. There I got the error message that there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
I think that my matrices are a bit too big (2048 x 2048 and some 4096 x 4096) for this solution. But for smaller matrices it is really a nice solution!
Wow, I have never thought that there are so many solutions for my problem!
And I have never thought that there are so many helpful people like here!